# Function was not declared in this scope, even though header file is present

Tags: c++

I'm trying to run some test code to learn c++, but I am getting an error telling me the `reverseDigits` function was not declared in the `main.cpp` scope:

`error: 'reverseDigits' was not declared in this scope`.

But the `#include "Solutions.h"` header was included in `main.cpp`, so I thought that it would be in scope.

I have checkout other questions, but the answers all relate to problems with circular header file inclusion, which I don't think is the problem here.

Do you know why I am seeing that error?

**Solution.h**

```
#ifndef SOLUTION_H
#define SOLUTION_H

class Solution {
public:
    Solution();
    ~Solution();
    int reverseDigits(int x);
};

#endif // SOLUTION_H
```

**Solution.cpp**

```
#include "Solution.h"
#include <string>

Solution::Solution()
{
}

Solution::~Solution()
{
}

int Solution::reverseDigits(int x) {
    std::string num_string = std::to_string(x);
    std::string reversed_num_string {};
    for (int i = num_string.length() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        reversed_num_string.push_back(num_string[i]);
    }
    return stoi(reversed_num_string);
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Solution.h"

int main()
{
    int x {123};
    int result = reverseDigits(x);
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you included the header file. No, that header file does not declare a function called `reverseDigits`. It declares some class with a method of that name, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: @Inian whoops my bad. Fixed that, still same error messsage tho.

Comment: @TinyTiger: You are not instantiating a object of the class `Solution`, does the function needs to be a member function or a separate one? What is your use case here?

Comment: Side-note: [`std::reverse` is a thing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse), and it operates efficiently in place. You don't need to define your own out-of-place reversing loop. The body of `reverseDigits` could simplify to `auto num_string = std::to_string(x); std::reverse(std::begin(num_string), std::end(num_string)); return stoi(num_string);`

Comment: @Inian, I was trying to reproduce something from a code test site locally. It basically boils down to my lack of experience, I can see how basic this problem was now. Not sure why it got down voted tho because the formatting of the question seems right, even if it was basic. Everyone is just here to learn.

Comment: @TinyTiger: I didn't down-vote the question FYI

Comment: @Inian Yep didn't think so :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared `reverseDigits` as a member function of the `Solution` class, then defined it without qualifying it as a member of `Solution` (Edit: You've since changed it to match declaration and definition, but at point of use, you're trying to use an unqualified function, not a member of a `Solution` object). The declaration in the `.h` file is visible, but the definition in the `.cpp` is unrelated, and not visible to `main.cpp`.

Declare the function outside the class (since it's clearly unrelated to the class), and it should work, changing to:

```
class Solution {
public:
    Solution();
    ~Solution();
};

int reverseDigits(int x); // NOT inside the class definition
```

I'll note: I have no idea why you have a `Solution` class at all. Defining `reverseDigits` doesn't require it, so I'm not seeing the point. If this is part of some automated evaluation framework, you'll have to give more details

Comment: Thanks! I'm working with an online code test practice site, all the questions are encased inside a Solution class, so I was trying to make something on my local computer where I could dump in the code to reproduce the test. This is working now thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Along with [ShadowRanger's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/364696/shadowranger) valid [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54084784/5291015), I'll highlight upon how you could have used the data as part of your `Solution` class and applied the function on it.

Refactoring your class to

```
class Solution {
 public:
     Solution(int data);
     ~Solution();
     int reverseDigits();
 private:
     int m_data;
};

Solution::Solution(int data)
{
    m_data = data;
}

Solution::~Solution()
{
}
```

Even though you could have used `std::reverse`, fixing the error on the `i>=0` is needed to have your own reverse function

```
int Solution::reverseDigits() {
    std::string num_string = std::to_string(m_data);
    std::string reversed_num_string {};
    for (int i = num_string.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        reversed_num_string.push_back(num_string[i]);
    }
    return stoi(reversed_num_string);
}
```

Now call it from your `main()` as

```
int main() {
    int x = 123;
    Solution sol(x);
    std::cout << sol.reverseDigits() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```